# What is crombie coat idiom meaning?

Tags: meaning

What is crombie coat idiom meaning?
I can't find any answers.

Comment: Could you post or link where this idiom is used? As a native AmE speaker I have never heard that phrase

Comment: I suspect this is referring to *abercrombie* which appears to be a padded jacket. The existence of Abercrombie & Fitch complicates searching, but [it seems to be possible](https://www.google.com/search?q=abercrombie+coat+-fitch&oq=abercrombie+coat+-fitch)

Comment: Hello, Mediator. Are you sure you haven't seen a nonce usage such as 'he was sporting the proverbial Abercrombie'?

Answer (score 1):

A [Crombie Coat](https://www.crombie.co.uk/lookbook/the-crombie-coat/) is one of range a classic outerwear made by the tailoring company Crombie (founded 1805 according to their website). It's a high quality, high status coat which has been worn by a number of famous people in the past including Winston Churchill, Cary Grant and members of The Beatles.

Crombie are a British tailoring company and have nothing to do with the American retailer Abercrombie and Fitch.

By the way, I found most of this information by googling "Crombie Coat".

Comment: But OP is asking about a (mooted) associated idiom, not merely the product. Perhaps something along the lines of 'it's built like a Mack' (proverbially solid and reliable).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The idiom, if it exists, will be related to the product. It will refer to men who are wealthy and part of the establishment. A bit like talking about 'pinstriped mentality' in the UK or, possibly, 'buttoned down mentality' in the US.

Comment: The question therefore is: _**Is** there a related idiom_? If not, the question is invalid. OP does not give any evidence that there actually _is_ such an idiom.